# events key is changing from what was defined

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a window in PySimpleGUI that contains many layouts and sub-windows, all initiate by
a button click and each one has a defined key to recognize the users choice.

The windows "event" parameter gets the users choice by: window.read().

For some reason, when the program starts, these keys (which are well defined before the GUI starts)
are changed by a number added to their original value.

Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: It maybe caused by duplicate key found in your layout, so the key of element will be replaced by `element.Key = str(element.Key) + str(self.UniqueKeyCounter); self.UniqueKeyCounter += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the keys in your PySimpleGUI program are being changed is likely due to the way that PySimpleGUI's event loop works.

PySimpleGUI uses a queue to store events that are generated by the user interacting with the GUI. When an event is generated (such as a button click), it is added to the queue and the window.read() function retrieves the next event from the queue and returns it.

If there are multiple events generated before window.read() is called, they will all be added to the queue and returned in the order that they were generated. This means that if the user clicks multiple buttons before window.read() is called, the keys for those buttons will be returned in the order that the buttons were clicked, not the order in which the buttons were defined.

One solution to this problem is to use the window.read(timeout=0) function instead of window.read(). This will make the window.read() function return immediately, allowing you to process events as soon as they are generated.

Another solution is to check the event queue before calling window.read() and if there is any event you can use window.read(timeout=0) to retrieve them.

```
while True:
event, values = window.read(timeout=0)
if event in (None, 'Exit'):
    break
# your code here
```

You can also use the window.read(timeout=0) in a loop to check the event queue for new events before processing the current event, and then continue to the next event only if the current event is processed.

It's important to note that the window.read() function is a blocking function, which means it will wait for an event to be generated before it returns. If you're using a non-blocking function like window.read(timeout=0) you should be careful with the design of the GUI and the logic, to avoid unexpected behaviours.